# Get variable on in animation function

Tags: jquery, variables, animation

maybe it stupid question.

example`

```
                nActive.find(".left").stop(true, true).animate({
                    top: -windowH
                }, 1000).promise().done(function() {
                    nestedparallax.eq(np).addClass("n-active");
                    nestedparallax.eq(np).removeClass("n-showD");
                    nestedparallax.eq(current).removeClass("n-active");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        flag = false;
                    }, 0);
                });
```

I have animation like this`

how can i  change "top" vith variable

for example var position = top it will write in animation top and if position = left it will take left on animation function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use object square bracket notation:

```
var oAnim = {}, position = 'top';
oAnim[position] = -windowH
nActive.find(".left").stop(true, true).animate(oAnim, 1000).promise(/*...*/);
```

Comment: nice solution Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate it before:

```
 var position = $('.left').offset();
 var left = position.left;
 var top = position.top;

  nActive.find(".left").stop(true, true).animate({
      top: (left < 0) ? top : left // this is an example of tertiary condition
  }, 1000).promise().done(function() {
      nestedparallax.eq(np).addClass("n-active");
      nestedparallax.eq(np).removeClass("n-showD");
      nestedparallax.eq(current).removeClass("n-active");
      setTimeout(function() {
           flag = false;
      }, 0);
  });
```

Maybe we can help better if you explain what you need better.